# using the HolidayAPI for bank holidays

Tags: javascript, api

**the Question:**
*How can I use the API to return a boolean value if the date is a bank holiday?*

I have done some research and found a great, and free API which contains bank holidays, however I am having trouble using it: http://holidayapi.com/

if i was to use this code:

```
 var year = 2016;
 var month = 3;
 var day = 25;
 var isAHoliday = false;

 $.getJSON(
          "http://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays?country=GB&year=" + year + "&month=" + month + "&day=" + day, function (data) {
                  console.log(data); //DOES NOT DISPLAY IN CONSOLE
                if (data.holidays.length > 0) {
                    // BANK HOLIDAY
                    isAHoliday = true;
                }
                else {
                    //IS NOT BANK HOLIDAY
                    //AND NOTHING NEEDS TO BE DONE
                }
          });
```

i want to be able to return a true or false value depending on if this returns any data or not, however im doing something wrong as **the getJSON request is not being called**, please could someone correct me where i have gone wrong?

http://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays?country=GB&year=2016&month=03&day=25 returns `{"status":200,"holidays":[{"name":"Good Friday","country":"GB","date":"2016-03-25"}]}`

http://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays?country=GB&year=2016&month=03&day=26 returns `{"status":200,"holidays":[]}`

**it appears this is causing an issue:** `"http://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays?country=GB&year=" + year + "&month=" + month + "&day=" + day;` if i pass one of the 2 URL's in above i get the correct result, I am having a play now with this

https://jsfiddle.net/dcxk6ens/

Comment: whats your question actually? are asking how to read values return from server or you are facing any error doing it?

Comment: If `$.getJSON` isn't being called then either the code is somewhere that it's not being executed (such as within a bad `if` statement) or you're not including the jQuery library before you're running this code.

Comment: not actual, now needs API key, "The API key parameter is required."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to return a `true` value if the selected date is a holiday, or `false` if it is not, you could use a function like this:

(Please note that jsfiddle will not execute any AJAX calls to URLs using the "http://" protocol, since it is not secure.)

```
function isDateAHoliday(y, m, d) {

    var jsonURL = "http://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays?country=GB&year=" + y + "&month=" + m + "&day=" + d;
    var isAHoliday = false;

    $.getJSON(jsonURL, function (data) {
        // If the date is a holiday
        if (data.holidays.length > 0) {
            // Do some things
            isAHoliday = true;
        }
        // Check values
        console.log("JSON DATA:  ", data);
        console.log("Holiday?:   " + isAHoliday);

        return isAHoliday;
    });
}

isDateAHoliday("2016", "3", "25");
```

If you wanted to return the name and country of the holiday as well, you could substitute `isAHoliday = data.holidays[0];` inside of the `if` statement.

Comment: if i put this in an if statement, for example if(isDateAHoliday("2016", "3", "25") == true) {} else if (isDateAHoliday("2016", "3", "25") == false}, neither are being hit

Comment: Ahh it must be because the `$.getJSON` runs asynchronously, the result is not received before the `if` statement evaluates.. I believe the best approach would be keeping the data manipulation logic inside the callback function so that the data is guaranteed to be available. I'll refactor the function a bit so it makes more sense

Comment: i took your answer and put it within a function which calls the JSON request every second, (odd cases where more than 1 was required) and works perfect, thanks for your post

Answer (score 1):

The `holidays` object must be called as a child of the returned `data` object:

Since the `holidays` object is an array you'll also need to use an index to access an item. Assuming there is at least one item returned, you would get the date like so:

```
var myDate = data.holidays[0].date;
```

However you should always check that there's at least one object in the array before getting the first one:

```
if(data.holidays.length > 0){...}
```

Incidentally, if all you want to do is check if there's a holiday on any particular day then this `if` statement is all you'll need, since an array length of more than zero means there's at least one holiday.

**Edit**

A full answer to your question, you could put this inside the `.done()` method:

```
var isAHoliday = false;
if(data.holidays.length > 0){
    // There's at least one holiday today!
    isAHoliday = true;
}
```

You don't have to declare a local variable, you'll probably use one that's declared elsewhere but that's up to you.

Comment: unfortunately using your logic is still not returning any values and myDate is still undefined

Comment: If you print the `data` object to the console, what is output?

Comment: nothing :/ as in it doesn't even hit the console.log() command

Comment: Can you post your full JavaScript or put it all into a JSFiddle?

Comment: posted above on answer at the bottom