# code excluding weekends and bank holidays

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write javascript code with html for getting business days excluding weekends and bank holidays. In short, when I enter a number, it should give the date of that number of days excluding weekends and bank holidays. For example, if I enter 4 it should give 22/02/207(considering today's date) excluding weekends along with holidays.

I was able to write the code to exclude weekends but couldn't figure out how to exclude bank holidays.

Comment: Unless there's a library or some JSON you could use that already exists, I imagine you're going to have to write the code for bank holidays as separate conditionals. What have you tried so far? Can you post some code.

Comment: Not all banks observe the same holidays. I assume you mean the list of federal government holidays in the US?

Comment: Perhaps you can reference the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36151042/2026606) for more information, which makes use of [Holiday API](https://holidayapi.com/).